# Machine Learning: autocategorization of strings - "Unknown label type" and "Bad Input Shape"

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to write a code that automatically categorizes my bank transactions using Python (and Scikit Learn). Currently I have about 1.7k transactions already classified with 70 categories (Labels) - I have about 3.5k total rows, but not all organized, this is my first try.
Basically I've imported a CSV file with:

```
Description             | Value | Label
RSHOP-SABORES DA -25/04 | -30   | Restaurants
RSHOP-MERCATTINO -28/04 | -23   | Bars
RSHOP-HORTISABOR -07/05 | -65   | Supermarket
TBI 3712.06663-9 tokpag | 1.000 | Salary
```

Description and Value are my features and Label, well, it's my label.
Description can get a bit complex with different characters and etc.
So I learned I should vectorize the description using Tf-IDF, and LabelEncode the labels.

---

For now, I have:

```
# Loads data
data = pd.read_csv('classifications.csv',
                    encoding='latin1',
                    error_bad_lines=False,
                    delimiter=';')

# Assigns features and labels - I chose to use only the description to make it simpler for a first time. I want to use the value later as well.
data.columns = ['desc', 'value', 'label']
data_base    = data.values
features_base= data_base[:,[0]]
labels_base  = data_base[:,[2]]

# Printing features returns a (1722,1) array - looks good.
print(features_base.shape)

# Printing labels returns a (1722,1) array - looks good.
print(labels_base.shape)

# Encodes labels, printing returns (1722,) - don't know why the "1" is missing on the y.
encoder       = LabelEncoder()
label_encoded = encoder.fit_transform((labels_base.astype(str)).ravel())
print(label_encoded.shape)

# Encodes features. Printing returns (1722, 1012) - don't know what's the "1012" on the y axis... the only thing I can think of the number of unique values on the vector, but can't be sure.
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
vectors     = vectorizer.fit_transform(features_base.ravel().astype('U'))
print(vectors.shape)


#Test
train_features, train_labels, test_features, test_labels = tts(vectors, label_encoded, test_size=0.2)
```

---

And then I try a few estimators, each with a different error (written on the first comment line):

```
# Random Forest Classifier - returns "ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous-multioutput'"
clf1 = RandomForestClassifier()
print("Using", clf1)
clf1.fit(train_features.toarray(), train_labels.toarray())
predictions1 = clf1.predict(test_features)
print( "\nPredictions:", predictions1)
score = 0
for i in range(len(predictions1)):
    if predictions[i] == test_labels[i]:
        score += 1
print("Accuracy:", (score / len(predictions)) * 100, "%")


# Decision Tree Classifier - returns "ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous-multioutput'"
clf2 = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
print("Using", clf2)
clf2.fit(train_features.toarray(), train_labels.toarray())
predictions2 = clf2.predict(test_features)
print( "\nPredictions:", predictions2)
score = 0
for i in range(len(predictions2)):
    if predictions[i] == test_labels[i]:
        score += 1
print("Accuracy:", (score / len(predictions)) * 100, "%")


#SVC Linear - returns "ValueError: bad input shape (345, 1012)"
clf3 = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
print("Using", clf3)
clf3.fit(train_features, train_labels)
predictions3 = clf3.predict(test_features)
print( "\nPredictions:", predictions3)
score = 0
for i in range(len(predictions1)):
    if predictions[i] == test_labels[i]:
        score += 1
print("Accuracy:", (score / len(predictions)) * 100, "%")


# SVC Non Linear - returns "ValueError: bad input shape (345, 1012)"
clf4 = svm.SVC()
print("Using", clf4)
clf4.fit(train_features.toarray(), train_labels.toarray())
predictions4 = clf4.predict(test_features)
print( "\nPredictions:", predictions4)
score = 0
for i in range(len(predictions1)):
    if predictions[i] == test_labels[i]:
        score += 1
print("Accuracy:", (score / len(predictions)) * 100, "%")
```

---

Final goal is to load a CSV file with Description/Amount, and it suggests me a Label (would be great to know the level of certainty of the suggestion).

To summarize:

1. Is the method to vectorize the description text reasonable? Any suggestion?
2. Am I right to use LabelEncoder to vectorize my labels?
3. What am I doing wrong? What's the error on the code?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you do `train_labels.toarray()` why are you not getting any errors? Your code seems too mixed up. You say you have `3.5k total rows` then, why does "`Printing features only returns a (1722,1) array`" ? Your example CSV has "`|`" as separator, but you use `delimiter=';'`??

Comment: 1) Don't know why. 2)Only using part of my available dataset, just to test the mechanism 3)That was just an example to make visualization simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the labels, since you use pandas, they should be passed to the classifier as categorical data. I'll post some code in a few minutes.

UPDATE:
Ok so there are some problems with your code. When developing a ML model on a new task, I suggest to start simple and then increment its complexity later, once you have a working prototype.
I have implemented the code only for RandomForestClassifier, you should be able to replicate it easily for the other classifiers in which you are interested. Here it is:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

data = pd.read_csv('classifications.csv',
                    encoding='latin1',
                    error_bad_lines=False,
                    delimiter=';')

data.columns = ['desc', 'value', 'label']
data['label'] = data['label'].astype('category')
data.info()
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
vectors    = vectorizer.fit_transform(data['desc'])
print('Shape: ',vectors.shape)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)

clf.fit(vectors,data['label'])
print('Score: {}'.format(clf.score(vectors,data['label'])))
clf.predict(vectorizer.transform(data['desc']))
```

The output of this code is:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 3 columns):
desc     4 non-null object
value    4 non-null float64
label    4 non-null category
dtypes: category(1), float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 340.0+ bytes
Shape:  (4, 14)
Score: 1.0
array(['Restaurants', 'Bars', 'Supermarket', 'Salary'], dtype=object)
```

A few comments:

1) If you use pandas, labels for classification should ideally be categorical data (pandas.Categorical). This decreases the possibility that the classifier interprets the labels as ordered data, and tries to sort its predictions accordingly.

2) If you are chaining multiple objects from sklearn, such as a vectoriser and a classifier, it is better to instantiate a Pipeline object by writing

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline([('vectorizer',TfidfVectorizer()),
                     ('classifier',RandomForestClassifier())])
```

This saves you the hassle of having to pass the output of the .transform or .fit_transform method from the vectorizer to the classifier anytime you need to give new data to the classifier, as the Pipeline does this automatically.

3) Set a random_state for the random classifiers, for reproducibility of the results.

4) It is not clear why you are trying to compute the score manually: the .score() method of the classifier computes the mean accuracy score automatically, and it prevents you from doing mistakes with functions such as len(predictions). When in another occasion you will try to predict a distribution of probability rather than a single spot prediction, if you develop the habit of calling len(predictions) you may end up computing on the wrong dimension on the array, without noticing. If, however, you want to have the score in percentage, and not in range 0 to 1, simply multiply the score returned by the .score() method by 100.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your thoughtful answer - really really helpful. A few comments on top of yours: 1) Got it, I tried to do that via "LabelEncoder", but that was just one unnecessary step when using Pandas Categories. 2) Don't know if I understand what you mean, but will do some research on the Pipeline. 3) Got it. 4) That was a snippet of a code I've got, but I noticed that there's a built in function to do that, which solves this specific problem... I'm getting 0.94 (Random Forest) and 0.93 (Decision Tree), which I'm guessing is a pretty good number.

Comment: was able to make predictions of new feature set with newPredictions = forest_model.predict(vectorizer.transform(newFeatures)). Next challenge is to include the ['value'] column on the original feature set to get better results. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. As far as the Pipeline constructor is concerned, please enjoy this page from the sklearn documentation: [Pipeline()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)
It will make your life much easier from here onward :)

Comment: Out of Curiosity: just got between 65-70% of my bank statement classification right!! Awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The bad input shape error is raised typically if the amount of features used while training are not equal to the testing features.

Comment: This is a helpful description of the error, but the OP had three parts to their question. Can you address the first two parts as well?